# Onebox suggested edits/revisions in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: oneboxed revision]

I would find it helpful to get a quick diff, the edit summary and any retagging in the onebox. Usually this would be enough to tell why the mentioner wants to share the revision without having to click a link.