# Specific-Revisions could use a onebox

Tags: feature-request, chat, revisions-list, onebox

Very similar to: [Onebox suggested edits/revisions in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119366/onebox-suggested-edits-revisions-in-chat)

I often find it helpful, especially when sorting flag-disputes and discussing posts to link to specific revisions of a post. This is ecouraged by the [share] button in the revisions history. But when I post that link in chat, there's just that link, and that's IMO more work than there need be.

Could we have a onebox for links to *specific* links to a *single revision* of a post for simplified site-moderation using chat?

For clarification:

The linked feature request is about *edits* (including suggested edits) as a diff. This is in fact a comparison of 2 revisisons. I would like to have a "snapshot" of a specific revision, without diffs or any additional information.